# AngularJS: $http interceptor change every call method to OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, restify, angular-http-interceptors

So, I'm trying to intercept the http calls to add the Authorization header on each call if exist.
This works well exept of the fact that no matter which http method I use (GET, POST, DELETE) it send the request with OPTIONS method instead. What am I doing wrong?

Server is nodejs with restify.

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('RequestService', function () {
    var token = null;

    var service = {
        setToken: function setToken(_token) {
            token = _token;
        },    

        getToken: function getToken() {
            return token;
        },

        request: function request(config) {
            if (token) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Token' + token;
            }
            return config;
        }

    }

    return service;
}).config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RequestService');
}
```

Comment: Are your calls cross-domains calls ?

Comment: Indeed, but I use chrome plugin to allow CORS, it's working fine without the interceptor @SamuelEUSTACHI

Comment: which plugin Do you use ?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement your own interceptor on Front-End side, you should remember about CORS:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-Type,x-requested-with,authorization123456,accept');
    next();
});
```

We should remember to set Acces-Controll-Allow on Methods as well as on Headers. In my case it's 'authorization123456' where I put my token which is added to every request from AngularJS.