# Call from Angular to webAPI on different domain is turned into OPTIONS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post, http-get

I am using asp.net WebAPI together with Angular. When I make a call from Angular to a method on my WebAPI, I get an error in Chrome (It is working fine in IE), and I can see with Fiddler that the call is made as an "OPTIONS" (I am only using $http.post and $http.get), in IE it is made as a post or a get.

I have tried to config a header to send with the request ('Content-Type': 'text/plain'), and then it is working fine in Chrome. But the problem is that I am using Authorization that also is in the header, and when i add Authorization in the header, the hack with content-type isn't working anymore.

I have also tried to add the NuGet packages "Cors" to the WebAPI (and enabled it in the controller [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]), but it has not made any changes.

Is there anyone that is having a solution for this problem?

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you also add the code in Global.asax's  Application_Start method when you use cors? Not just add `EnableCorsAttribute`on action

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors();
```

or you don't need to use cors lib,it is also used when you add children node in `web.config`'s node `system.webServer`

```
<httpProtocol>    
  <customHeaders>    
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />    
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />    
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" />    
  </customHeaders>    
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I do that I get the following error: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Comment: I have also tried adding the parametes to web.config, but still the same problem :-/ But when adding 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' to the header it Works. But then there is the problem with the Authorization

Comment: about Authorization ,maybe you can find "Passing Credentials in Cross-Origin Requests" in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thank you very much everybody for your comments. Finally it Works, I did not find the exact error, but is using CORS and after a lot of attempts, it finally worked 

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add an httpInterceptor and add the Access-Control headers as describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592616/929874) of similar question

Comment: How and where do I Implement that?